# How do you call members that serve a organization/community but also have authority that normal community people have not

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you call members that serve a organization/community  but also have authority that normal community people have not

Comment: I think you're looking for disjoint terms (though there might be a small overlap).

Comment: I am actually looking a good word for people who serve a community but also have authority.

Comment: Have you looked up synonyms of 'leaders'?

Comment: People who use their authority in service of the community. Rather like Stack Exchange moderators, or many police forces, or even the Pope ("Servant of the Servants of God"). Intriguing question. Is there a general term?

Comment: I can't post this as answer because it is not general enough, but it may entertain you. In Scots, such a person may be a "high heidyin" = high-up person in an organisation. See http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/general/scots.html. Loosely, "a high head one", or one who stands out from their group by virtue of authority.

Comment: Related (at least some of the answers): [What is a single word for a ruling representative of a supreme leader who ....](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41296/what-is-a-single-word-for-a-ruling-representative-of-a-supreme-leader-who-carrie/41298#41298). eg _steward; panjandrum_.

Comment: What do you mean by "serve a community"? You mean work in a job that provides a public service, such as teacher or firefighter? Or having a governing/ruling role in a community, such as a mayor or councillor? Or having a position that involves supervising other members of the community at some task (e.g. running a food bank or soup kitchen)?

Comment: @StuartF for example a religious community in which there are people who have more authority to say or initiate things. It can be that a normal religous member is a supporter of the community but apart from that has no extra authorities.